react native app open my react website, need to add button that moving back to application
at my work we're working with React native and React.
The application moves me to the React web and I tried to add a button that moves me back to React-native application without success
Hey everyone, at my work we're working with React native and React.
on my React native application we've got a section that moves the user to the contact page.
TSX CODE:
<TouchableOpacity
            style={styleObject.button}
            onPress={() =>
              WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(CONTACT_URI)
            }>

it works great, it opens the currect page on our web. I tried to add an X button that closes that window and goes back to the app like this:
TSX CODE:
{width <= 768 && <img src={closeMobileNavWhite} className='close-btn' onClick={() => {
            window.close();
          }} />}

is this the correct way to close the browser? the browser doesn't close after the window.close();

Does this answer your question? Close current browser tab on button click, using reactjs
